# Gauge invariance and Ward Identity?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, yang-mills, self-energy, ward-identity

I have to work on vacuum polarization and gauge contributions for a given problem.

[image]

I have to compute and show that their sum is gauge invariant, which according to the exercise, is equivalent to showing that

$$
p_\mu M^{\mu,\nu;a,b} = 0
$$
or equivalently,
$$
M^{\mu,\nu;a,b} (p) = \delta^{ab}(g^{\mu \nu} p ^2 - p^\mu p ^\nu)\Pi(p^2)
$$
Why does $M$ having this form imply that it is gauge invariant? I have read that the fact that this holds is due to current conservation and also the Ward Identity. I am looking for insights on this and how to see gauge invariance from it.